# WPF ListBoxItems with DataTemplates - How do I reference the CLR Object bound to ListBoxItem from within the DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate, listboxitem

I have a ListBox, that's bound to an `ObservableCollection`.

Each `ListBoxItem` is displayed with a `DataTemplate`. I have a button in my `DataTemplate`, that when clicked, needs a reference to the member of the `ObservableCollection` it's part of the DataTemplate for. I can't use the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property because the item does not become selected when clicking the button.

So either: I need to figure out how to properly set `ListBox.SelectedItem` when the mouse hovers, or when the button is clicked. Or I need to figure out another way to get a reference to the CLR Object bound to the `ListBoxItem` that the button belongs to. The second option seems cleaner, but either way is probably OK.

Simplified code segment below:

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="postBody">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=author}"/>
        <Button Click="DeleteButton_Click">Delete</Button>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource postBody}"/>
```

C#:

```
private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Where mah ListBoxItem?");
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally speaking people will be interested in a CLR object directly bound to the `ListBoxItem`, not the actual `ListBoxItem`.  If you had a list of posts for example you could use your existing template of:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="postBody" TargetType="{x:Type Post}">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=author}"/>
    <Button Click="DeleteButton_Click">Delete</Button>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource postBody}" 
  ItemSource="{Binding Posts}"/>
```

and in your code-behind, your `Button`'s `DataContext` is equal to your `DataTemplate`'s `DataContext`.  In this case a `Post`.

```
private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
  var post = ((Button)sender).DataContext as Post;
  if (post == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid DataContext");

  Console.WriteLine(post.author);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, and you've managed to also fix the wording of my question. I will edit it as you're right, I'm interested in the bound CLR object, not the ListBoxItem itself.

Answer (score 3):

You have several possibilities, depending on what you need to do.

First, the main question is: "why do you need this"? Most of the time, there is no real use for a reference to the container item (not saying this is your case, but you should elaborate). If you are databinding your listbox, there is rarely a case for that.

Second, you can get the item from the Listbox, using `myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem()`, provided your listbox is named `MyListBox`. From the sender parameter, you can get back the actual item that was templated through, for example (where `XXX` is the type of you databound data):

```
Container = sender as FrameworkElement;
if(sender != null)
{
    MyItem = Container.DataContext as XXX;
    MyElement = MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(MyItem); // <-- this is your ListboxItem.
}
```

You can find an example an [this blog](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=7). She uses the index method, but the Item method is similar.

Comment: Good answer to the question as originally worded. bendewey correctly assumed I didn't mean what I said I did, but this is also appreciated. Voted up.