# Items in ObservableCollection<string> do not update when bound to a WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, string, data-binding, listbox

I should like to manipulate an `ObservableCollection` of `string`s by binding it to the `ItemsSource` property of a `ListBox` and setting the item template to a `TextBox`.

My problem is that the items in the `ObservableCollection` do not get updated when I edit them in the `TextBox` items that the `ListBox` contains. What am I doing wrong?

The XAML of the minimum working example is

```
    <Window x:Class="ListBoxUpdate.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="ListBoxUpdate" Height="300" Width="300"
>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Show items" Click="HandleButtonClick"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="textBlock" />
    </Grid>
    <ListBox
        Grid.Column="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Strings, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

whilst the corresponding code-behind is

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Windows;

    namespace ListBoxUpdate
    {
        public partial class Window1 : Window
        {
            public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get; set; }

            public Window1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                Strings = new ObservableCollection<string>(new string[] { "one", "two", "three" });
                this.DataContext = this;
            }

            void HandleButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                string text = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < Strings.Count; i++) {
                    text += Strings[i] + Environment.NewLine;
                }

                textBlock.Text = text;
            }
        }
    }
```

Your advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Strings are immutable, they can't be changed.  If you want to be able to change the text, you will need a wrapper class with a string property.  Then you can change the property on the class.

Comment: @BrandonKramer: Thank you very much, you are right. I replaced the strings with a StringWrapper internal class and with that, it works.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @BrandonKramer: If you post your comment as an answer, I should be glad to accept it. I am rather inexperienced in forums like this, but I think it would be impolite to answer my own question on the basis of the comment of someone else.

Comment: @tethered: actually, this doesn't have anything to do with the `string` type being immutable. It's simply because WPF binding can't change the source object being bound to; it can only change properties on that object. But yes, the answer is still the same: put the value you want to change in a property of the source object, instead of making it the source object. You should feel free to self-answer...Brandon may not want to take the time to write a full-blown answer, but you can easily post the code you had to write to fix the problem, since you already have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments by @BrandonKramer and @Peter Duniho show, the solution is that data binding cannot change the object itself to which it is bound, only the properties of that object.

Consequently, I have to create a wrapper class whose property will then be the string I want to manipulate. The code-behind is now

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace ListBoxUpdate
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<StringWrapper> Strings { get; set; }

        public class StringWrapper 
        {
            public string Content { get; set; }

            public StringWrapper(string content)
            {
                this.Content = content;
            }

            public static implicit operator StringWrapper(string content)
            {
                return new Window1.StringWrapper(content);
            }
        }

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Strings = new ObservableCollection<StringWrapper>(new StringWrapper[] { "one", "two", "three" });
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        void HandleButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string text = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < Strings.Count; i++) {
                text += Strings[i].Content + Environment.NewLine;
            }

            textBlock.Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

and the XAML has to be modified only at one point

```
<ListBox
    Grid.Column="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Strings, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Thank you, @BrandonKramer and @Peter Duniho.

UPDATE: I felt uncomfortable with defining a wrapper just to manipulate objects, and the problem of editing an object itself in a list and not one of its properties seemed to me universal, so I tried to find another solution. I rather decided to hook to the `LostFocus` event of the `TextBox` in the `ItemTemplate`.

In this case, the problem is finding the index in the `ListBox` from the templated `TextBox` that is just losing focus. I cannot use the `SelectedIndex` property of the `ListBox` as at the time when a `LostFocus` fires, it is already set to a different `ListBoxItem`.

I searched quite a bit and have found Dennis Troller’s answer here: [WPF ListBoxItems with DataTemplates - How do I reference the CLR Object bound to ListBoxItem from within the DataTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765984/wpf-listboxitems-with-datatemplates-how-do-i-reference-the-clr-object-bound-to?rq=1) The trick is to get the `DataContext` of the `TextBox` losing focus and use the `ItemContainerGenerator` of the `ListBox` to first identify the container (with `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem`) then obtain the index in the list (with `ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer`).

The code-behind is now

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace ListBoxUpdate
{

    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get; set; }

        public Window1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            this.Strings = new ObservableCollection<string>(new string[] { "one", "two", "three" });
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        void HandleButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string text = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < Strings.Count; i++) {
                text += Strings[i] + Environment.NewLine;
            }

            textBlock.Text = text;
        }

        void HandleTextBoxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765984/wpf-listboxitems-with-datatemplates-how-do-i-reference-the-clr-object-bound-to?rq=1, @Dennis Troller's answer.
            int index;
            object item;
            DependencyObject container;
            TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;

            if (textBox == null) return;

            item = textBox.DataContext;
            container = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);

            if (container != null) {
                index = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(container);
                if (textBox.Text != Strings[index]) {
                    Strings[index] = textBox.Text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with the full XAML as follows (I made the binding to the text one-way):

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxUpdate.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ListBoxUpdate" Height="300" Width="300"
    >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Show items" Click="HandleButtonClick"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="textBlock" />
        </Grid>
        <ListBox
            x:Name="listBox"
            Grid.Column="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox 
                        Text="{Binding ., Mode=OneWay}"
                    LostFocus="HandleTextBoxLostFocus"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```