# ListBox binding to ObservableCollection<string>

Tags: c#, listbox, observablecollection, datacontext

In the following class, the itemssource of a listbox should bind to the Interfaces property.

```
public class BaseClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private const string TYPE_TITLE = "Type";

    private string  _Type;

    public string Type
    {
        get { return _Type; }
        set { _Type = value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged(PropertyChanged, TYPE_TITLE); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Interfaces { get; set; }

    public BaseClass()
    {
        Interfaces = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _Type = null;
        Interfaces.Clear();
    }
}
```

In that list box the selected item should be able to edit as the inline edit scenario,

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BaseClass_Interfaces_InlineEdit_Template">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=., NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="BaseClass_Interfaces_InlineView_Template">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="BaseClass_Iterfaces_ItemStyle_Template">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BaseClass_Interfaces_InlineView_Template}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BaseClass_Interfaces_InlineEdit_Template}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The ListBox has a container as a parent hierarchy which its DataContext property bind to an instance of BaseClass hence the ListBox could bind to the Interfaces property.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Interfaces, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single"
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BaseClass_Iterfaces_ItemStyle_Template}" />
```

- The list box before select any item
  [image: The list box before select any item]
- Editing the selected item
  [image: Editing the selected item]
- Another item select after edit and the changes doesn't affected
  [image: Selection changed after edit]

There are two problems :

1. The TextBox  should have "Path=." otherwise the "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath." exception message received.
2. With consider the above problem, the ObservableCollection items never updated after text changed!!!!!!

Comment: can you upload an image of your wanted UI?

Comment: The images of the UI added!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!
My wondering was about the text box which the text property changed but the changes does not propagated to the source, based on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459063/items-in-observablecollectionstring-do-not-update-when-bound-to-a-wpf-listbox) the binding mechanism works on the properties of sources in the other words the change of the properties monitors not the object itself.
The solution is a wrapper class around the string, i wrote this wrapper before for another primitive type (bool).

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }

    public Wrapper(T value = default(T))
    {
        Item = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Wrapper<T>(T item)
    {
        return new Wrapper<T>(item);
    }

    public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> item)
    {
        if (null != item)
            return item.Item;

        return default(T);
    }
}
```

So the editing data template change as follow

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BaseClass_Interfaces_InlineEdit_Template">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Item, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

And every thing work as charm!!!